# error on integrating spring data jpa with spring batch admin

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch-admin

```
o.s.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productfeedSvc': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:
private com.dealwallet.productFeed.repository.ProductFeedRepository 
com.dealwallet.productFeed.svc.impl.ProductSvcImpl.productFeedRepository;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productFeedRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: **org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.setTransactionManagerBeanName(Ljava/lang/String;)**V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
```

I am using spring data jpa with spring batch admin,
 i configured application-context.xml and persistance.xml,
 when am running this in tomcat i got this error.

Answer (score 0):

It says there is problem in `auto-wiring`.
So check these items:
- Make sure your class (the one which is using the other) has setter for that property.
- Make sure your class's property (the one which is using the other) has the exact name of the other class bean id.
- Make sure you have enabled `annotation`s.